# Converting a case class to CSV in Scala

Tags: scala, csv, macros, case-class

Is there a elegant way to convert a case class to a CSV value.

For example -

```
 case class Person( name : String, age : Int, gender: String, address : Option[String])
```

I was thinking about using macros but would like to know if there are any other alternatives.

NOTE: The case class doesn't contain any user defined fields.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about `implicits` and `productIterator`?

```
implicit class CSVWrapper(val prod: Product) extends AnyVal {
    def toCSV() = prod.productIterator.map{
                    case Some(value) => value
                    case None => ""
                    case rest => rest
                  }.mkString(",")
}

Person("name", 30, "male", None).toCSV()
```

Comment: Good idea, but needs proper escaping of `"`: `scala> Person("\"", 30, "male", None).toCSV()
res1: String = ",30,male,`

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov I will leave those nitty gritty details to the implementer as maybe their usecase allows it

Comment: what about `value.toString.replace("\"", "\\\"")`

Answer (score 11):

Yes, in Scala there is a way to convert a case class to CSV without adding boilerplate at all. For instance [PureCSV](https://github.com/melrief/PureCSV), based on the amazing [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library, can do it:

```
scala> import purecsv.safe._
scala> case class Interval(start: Long, end: Long)
scala> Interval(10,20).toCSV()
res1: String = 1,10
scala> Seq(Interval(1,10),Interval(11,20)).toCSV("|")
res2: String =
1|10
11|20
```

Note: I'm the author of PureCSV.

Comment: I prefer PureCSV to the accepted answer because handling CSV correctly is all about the nitty gritty parsing details. These already are handled by http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ library PureCSV relies on. In addition PureCSV provides a nice Scala integration.

Comment: Problem of PureCSV is that it does not work for embedded case classes

Comment: PureCSV does not create a CSV header from the case class variable names.

Answer (score 2):

[product-collections](http://github.com/marklister/product-collections) will also produce csv for you. product-collections scales pretty well;  it's reflection free & compatible with scala-js.

```
import com.github.marklister.collections.io._
case class Foo(a:Int,b:String)
Seq(Foo(1,"hello"),Foo(2,"World")).csvIterator.mkString("\n")

res2: String =
1,"hello"
2,"World"
```

I'm the author of product-collections

Answer (score 0):

To complete the accepted answer, you can also match the Product type with pattern matching :

```
implicit class CSVWrapper(val prod: Product) extends AnyVal {
  def toCSV: String = prod.productIterator.map{
    case p: Product =>  p.toCSV
    case rest => rest
  }.mkString(",")
}
```

This would work with embedded case classes :

```
case class Address(street: String, town: String, country: Option[String])
case class Person( name : String, age : Int, gender: Option[String], address : Option[Address])

Person("myname", 30, Some("male"), Some(Address("mystreet", "city", None))).toCSV
// result :
// myname,30,male,mystreet,city,
```

Comment: Would not be good if there was something after address: `None` would become a single empty field, skipping 2 columns...